# Select multiple rows / columns in PowerPoint table using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint, selection

I'm looking for a way to select more than one row (or column) in a PowerPoint table using VBA (the two rows or columns being next to each other). This is something that can be achieved manually using the mouse.

E.g. here to try and select the first two rows of the selected table, I have tried adding `Replace:=False` but this doesn't work (compilation error).

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Table.Rows(1).Select
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Table.Rows(2).Select Replace:=False
```

Any clue on how to achieve this?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: As a general rule, it's better not to select anything, and in most cases you don't need to. What do  you want to accomplish here?

Comment: Hi Steve - select is precisely what I would like to achieve in this case. I'm trying to recreate the CTRL + SPACEBAR and SHIFT + SPACEBAR shortcuts from Excel that allow a user to select entire columns and rows, but within PowerPoint (using AutoHotKey afterwards). My macro works for one row (or column) in PowerPoint, but I would like to make it work also for several rows / columns, just like in Excel (e.g. if you select two cells and hit SHIFT + SPACEBAR, the two rows are selected)

Comment: Dang.  Spent a good amount of time playing with this but no joy. Odd that it shouldn't work, but there it is.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time Steve.

Answer (score 2):

I have finally found out that select rows and select columns are native built-in functions in PowerPoint - they allow to select multiple rows or columns if the user selected multiple cells.

According to Microsoft's documentation, the name of those commands are `TableRowSelect` and `TableColumnSelect` ([see here][1] for the command names of built-in ribbon buttons in Office softwares).

Those buttons can be executed in VBA the following way, example here with the SelectRow() sub.

```
Sub SelectRows()

'First we check some conditions to make sure that the user has selected a table, otherwise an error will occur if the user didn't select anything or if it selected something else than a table
If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = 0 Then Exit Sub  'if nothing is selected the sub stops
If ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub 'if more than one shape is selected the sub stops
If ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).HasTable = False Then Exit Sub 'if this selected shape is not a table the sub stops
   
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("TableRowSelect")

End Sub
```

To link this sub to the SHIFT + SPACE shortcut, this can be implemented in AutoHotKey the following way in a .ahk file:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class PPTFrameClass
PPApp := ComObjActive("PowerPoint.Application")
    
; SHIFT + SPACE to select rows
+Space::

If PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = 0 { 
Return 
}
If PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Shaperange.Count <> 1 { 
Return 
}
If PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Shaperange.HasTable = False {
 Return 
 }

PPApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("TableRowSelect")

Return
```

The same way, CTRL + SPACE can be associated to the select columns command - note that this will override PowerPoint's CTRL + SPACE built-in shortcut which removes formatting to selected text.
[1]: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-fluent-ui-command-identifiers